# Making my computer prompt me with a predeterminedquestion whenever I open firefox

Tags: java, macos, firefox

I'm inspired by reading this from John Conway's wikipedia page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway#Algorithmics

I want to have a window pop up whenever I open firefox to ask a question that I code. I'd type in a response in a text box and upon hitting return it would display the answer and whether I'm correct or not. What I'm thinking of right now would be I'd get a random number in centimeters between, say, 0 and 300 and I would try to get the correct amount of inches it corresponds to.

I have no idea how to even start going about this. How do you make some program execute when I click and turn on a browser? I have some experience with swing so perhaps we could use that but I've looked through some of the swing library to no avail. I put the java tag there because it's the language I'm most familiar with so a solution in java would be best if possible. Also, are there any good resources to learn how to do stuff like this?

I think my main problem is getting some prewritten code to run upon opening the browser. The rest I can probably deal with in swing but I'm not completely sure.

Lastly, sorry for the non-space between predetermined and question, but the site doesn't let me use the second word in the title even though it makes sense here.

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) looks relevant

it talks about controlling web browsers, sounds like a tool for you

Answer (score 1):

This question is borderline off-topic for SO, but not hard to answer and interesting enough to grab my attention so I'll go ahead and do so.

You'd have to code all of this yourself, but you could use InnoSetup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to create yourself an installable Java program and follow these directions to launch Firefox after you answer your predetermined question:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/7710/how-to-run-external-.exe-programs-from-java